# Laravel редирект на подтверждение почты

Tags: laravel

Почему это не работает?

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public function __construct()
{
    if(Auth::check()){
         $this->middleware(['verified']);
    }
}
```

Я хочу чтобы после авторизации пользователя постоянно перекидывало на страницу с подтверждением почты, до тех пор пока он ее не подтвердит.
Функция Auth::check() не срабатывает, как это можно сделать?
Laravel-8;

Comment: а разве ```middleware``` добавляется не к маршруту?

Comment: Не только к маршруту

Comment: Попробовать через реквест?

Comment: Walfter,  пробывал но у меня все время значение NULL,но я думаю я что-то не так делал. Если не сложно дайте пример как.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Документация https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification#model-preparation

Недостаточно добавить посредника

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
}
```

Модель `User` должна реализовывать интерфейс `MustVerifyEmail`

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail {
    use Notifiable;
    // ...
}
```

Хорошая статья https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-7-email-verification-exampleexample.html